# Writing and reading data error java

Tags: java, class, oop, parameters

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MovieSeating.assignCustomerAt(MovieSeating.java:27)
    at Assignment8.main(Assignment8.java:84)

After I pull data from a txt file with a list of first and last names, it gives and error after I try and assign the name to a certain element that IS within the bounds of the 2d array

Thanks!

---

```
    public class Customer
     {
       private String lastName;
       private String firstName;

       // This constructor sets the first name and last name to "???�
       public Customer()
       {
              lastName = "???";
              firstName = "???";
       }

      // This constructor constructs a Customer object  given the last name and first name
       public Customer(String customerInfo)
       {
             int space = customerInfo.indexOf(" ");
             firstName = customerInfo.substring(0, space).trim();
             lastName = customerInfo.substring(space+1).trim();

       }

       // This constructor cConstructs a Customer object using the string containing customer's info.
       // It uses the StringTokenizer to extract first name, last name, id, the number of matinee tickets,
       // and the number of normal tickets.
       public Customer(String lName, String fName)
       {
             lastName = lName;
             firstName = fName;

       }

       // This method sets the last name.
       public void setLastName(String lName)
       {
             lastName = lName;
       }
       // This method sets the first name.
       public void setFirstName(String fName)
       {
             firstName = fName;
       }

       // This method returns the last name.
       public String getLastName()
       {
             return lastName;
        }
       // This method returns the first name.
       public String getFirstName()
       {
             return firstName;
       }

       // This method checks if a customer object passed as a parameter and itself (customer object)
       // are same using their last names and first names.
       public boolean equals(Customer other)
       {
             if (lastName.equals(other.lastName) && firstName.equals(other.firstName))
                 return true;
             else
                 return false;
       }

       // This method returns a string containing a customer's initials
       // (first characters of firstName and lastName.)
       public String toString()
       {
               String result = firstName.charAt(0) + "." + lastName.charAt(0) + ".";
               return result;
       }


     } // end of the class Customer
```

---

```
    class MovieSeating 
    {
        private String[][] Seats;
        public MovieSeating(int rowNum, int columnNum)
        {
            String [][] Seats = new String[rowNum][columnNum];
            for (int r = 0; r < rowNum; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < columnNum; c++)
                {
                    Seats[r][c] = "?.?";
                }
            }
        }

        private Customer getCustomerAt(int row, int col)
        {
            System.out.println("Customer at row " + row + " and col " + col + "." );
            System.out.println(Seats[row][col]);

        }

        public boolean assignCustomerAt(int row, int col, Customer tempCustomer)
        {
            if (Seats[row][col].equals("?.?"))
            {
                tempCustomer = Seats[row][col];
                return true;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Seat taken..");
                return false;
            }

        }

        public boolean checkBoundaries(int row, int col)
        {
            if (col < 0 || row < 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Assignment8
    {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
       {

           MovieSeating theatreSeating;
           Customer tempCustomer;
           int requestedRow, requestedCol, row, col, rowNum, columnNum;
           String line, fileName;

           // to read input from a KEYBOARD.
           Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

           // Ask a user to enter a number of rows for a movie theatre seating from a KEYBOARD.
           System.out.println("Please enter a number of rows for a movie theatre seating.");
           rowNum = stdin.nextInt();

           // Ask a user to enter a number of columns for a movie theatre seating from a KEYBOARD.
           System.out.println("Please enter a number of columns for a movie theatre seating.");
           columnNum = stdin.nextInt();

           // instantiate a MovieSeating object
           theatreSeating = new MovieSeating(rowNum, columnNum);

           // get a file name read from a KEYBOARD.
           System.out.println("Please enter a file name");
           fileName = stdin.next();

           // create FileReader and BufferedReader object to
           // read from a file.
           FileReader fr = new FileReader (fileName);
           BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader (fr);

           /*** reading a customer's information from a FILE ***/
           line = inFile.readLine();

           /*** we will read line by line until we read the end of a given file ***/
           while (line != null)
           {
               System.out.println("\nA customer information is read from a file.");
               // printing information read from a file.
               System.out.println(line);

               // creating a customer object using information from a file
               tempCustomer = new Customer(line);

               // Ask a user to decide where to seat a customer by asking for row and column of a seat
               System.out.println("Please enter a row number where the customer wants to sit.");
               requestedRow = stdin.nextInt();
               row = requestedRow -1;

               System.out.println("Please enter a column number where the customer wants to set.");
               requestedCol =  stdin.nextInt();
               col = requestedCol -1;

               // Checking if the row number and column number are valid (exist in the theatre that we created.)
               if (theatreSeating.checkBoundaries(row, col) == false)
               {
                    System.out.println("\nrow or column number is not valid.");
                    System.out.println("A customer " + tempCustomer.getFirstName() + " " + tempCustomer.getLastName() + " is not assigned a seat.");
               }
               else
               {
                  // Assigning a seat for a customer
                  if (theatreSeating.assignCustomerAt(row, col, tempCustomer) == true)
                  {
                    System.out.println("\nThe seat at row " + row + " and column " + col + " is assigned to the customer " + tempCustomer.toString());
                    System.out.println(theatreSeating);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    System.out.println("\nThe seat is taken.");
                  }
                }
               // Read next line in a FILE
               line = inFile.readLine();

           }//end of the while loop
             // Closing the file
           inFile.close();

         }

      }
```

Comment: Can you post the error please? (What line is the error on?)

Comment: ./MovieSeating.java:27: error: incompatible types
   tempCustomer = Seats[row][col];
                            ^
  required: Customer
  found:    String
1 error

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure since I didn't run the code and I just looking at it in my browser but: Seats[row][col].equals("?.?") is the problem. If you get an empty seat where no Customer is on, Seats[XX][YY] will return 'null'. Which means "empty" or "nothing". So can't call "equals" on null since null is nothing and you can't call something on nothing (sounds funny but is true). Instead, test whether it is null or not: if(Seats[XXX][YYY] == null)

Answer (score 4):

O.K., here's your problem:

You have an array called `seats`. It is of the type `String`. So it could hold strings like "???" or "free seat". However, you try to put customers in it. That's exactly what the error message says: `error: incompatible types tempCustomer = Seats[row][col]; ^ required: Customer found: String 1 error`

Now you have a couple of options. A very simple one would be to change the type of the array to Customers. Instead of putting "???" on the free seats, put nothing to them. After creating an array, each "slot" is `null`, which actually means "nothing".

BTW: You are violating many recommended rules for writing Java code. This are just simple things and don't affect your code (it will run anyway ;). But it is a good practice to respect these unwritten rules (like put the { in the same line as the function-head or naming variables no with an upper-case letter).

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Can you help me figure out why I am getting a null pointer exception error when I try to write the username from a txt file to the 2d array space within the proper bounds?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at MovieSeating.assignCustomerAt(MovieSeating.java:27)
 at Assignment8.main(Assignment8.java:84)

Answer (score 2):

As the error message itself say you are trying to assign String to Customer. At line 27

```
tempCustomer = Seats[row][col];
```

Seats is an String array and will return String which are trying to assign to Customer

Answer (score 1):

The code to put a customer to the seat should be:

```
private Customer getCustomerAt(int row, int col) 
{
    System.out.println("Customer at row " + row + " and col " + col + "." );
    System.out.println(Seats[row][col]);
            /** return customer */
    return new Customer(Seats[row][col]);
}

public boolean assignCustomerAt(int row, int col, Customer tempCustomer) 
{
    if (Seats[row][col].equals("?.?")) 
    {
       /** put a customer to the seat */
        Seats[row][col] = tempCustomer.toString();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Seat taken..");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now when I run it after I fix it and assign a space in the array to a name read from the text file I get :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at MovieSeating.assignCustomerAt(MovieSeating.java:27)
 at Assignment8.main(Assignment8.java:84)

Comment: @Ryan what is in text file (what is initial data) you are using?

Comment: You can name it anything..It is a txt file called customerData.txt that holds 5 random first and last names separated by a space.
First Last
John Smith
George Bush
etc, and they are all on separate lines.